# There is a notice in the single-product.php woocommerce, The photo is in the description

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

[Notice: Theme without comments.php is deprecated since version 3.0 with no alternative available. Please include a comments.php template in your theme. in /--/--/--/--/wp-includes/functions.php on line 3984.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jvxAr.jpg)

There is a notice in the single-product.php woocommerce file
,I see list of comments but have this notice

also i added comments.php in my theme

this comments.php file in theme

```
<?php
 /*
 * If the current post is protected by a password and the visitor has not yet
 * entered the password we will return early without loading the comments.
 */
 if ( post_password_required() )
    return;
?>
 <div id="comments" class="comments-area">
    <?php if ( have_comments() ) : ?>
        <h2 class="comments-title">
            <?php
                printf( _nx( 'One thought on &ldquo;%2$s&rdquo;', '%1$s thoughts on &ldquo;%2$s&rdquo;', get_comments_number(), 'comments title', 'ivanhoe' ),
                    number_format_i18n( get_comments_number() ), '<span>' . get_the_title() . '</span>' );
            ?>
        </h2>
        <ol class="commentlist">
            <?php
                wp_list_comments( array(
                    'style'       => 'ol',
                    'short_ping'  => true,
                    'avatar_size' => 74,
                ) );
            ?>
        </ol><!-- .comment-list -->
        <?php
            // Are there comments to navigate through?
            if ( get_comment_pages_count() > 1 && get_option( 'page_comments' ) ) :
        ?>
        <nav class="navigation comment-navigation" role="navigation">
            <h1 class="screen-reader-text section-heading"><?php _e( 'Comment navigation', 'ivanhoe' ); ?></h1>
            <div class="nav-previous"><?php previous_comments_link( __( '&larr; Older Comments', 'ivanhoe' ) ); ?></div>
            <div class="nav-next"><?php next_comments_link( __( 'Newer Comments &rarr;', 'ivanhoe' ) ); ?></div>
        </nav><!-- .comment-navigation -->
        <?php endif; // Check for comment navigation ?>
        <?php if ( ! comments_open() && get_comments_number() ) : ?>
        <p class="no-comments"><?php _e( 'Comments are closed.' , 'ivanhoe' ); ?></p>
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endif; // have_comments() ?>
    <?php comment_form(); ?>
 </div><!-- #comments -->
```

Comment: As the error message says: the theme you are using is missing the comments.php template file. Please ask the theme provider to include this template or create the comments template file on your own.

Comment: I am the designer of this theme myself also i add comments.php file in my theme and template but i have this notice in single-product.php woocommerce file but i dont have this notice in single-post.php file

Comment: can you post your comments.php file?

Comment: and are you using this function `comments_template()` anywhere any plugins and theme? check in all plugins

Comment: woocommerce 3.5.1 and wordpress 4.9.8, yes i used comments_template in single-post.php

Comment: my function in single-post.php file is `<?php comments_template(null, true); ?>`

Comment: `<?php comments_template(null, true); ?>` remove this code and check

Comment: i removed that but i still have this notice

Comment: can i send my theme for you?

Comment: send your email

Comment: i copy that remove your email

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this code in functions.php file

```
add_theme_support('woocommerce');
```